# Firebase + NodeJS: Cannot get any data, console.log of data has weird JSON object

Tags: json, node.js, firebase

I've looked around, but I can't seem to find anything related to my problem, which is:

I'm trying to simply get data from Firebase.  Here what my code looks like

```
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator(process.env.FIREBASE_SECRET);
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var firebaseRef = new Firebase(process.env.FIREBASE_URL); //just the base URL
var fbToken = tokenGenerator.createToken({uid:process.env.FIREBASE_SERVER_UID});

firebaseRef.authWithCustomToken(fbToken, function (fbErr, authData){
if(fbErr){
  console.log('fb login/auth failed');
  console.log(fbErr);
} else {
  console.log('fb login/auth success');
  var pendingMessagesRef = firebaseRef.child('pending'); //trying to get the baseURL/pending Firebase objects
  pendingMessagesRef.once('value', function (pendingMessages){
    console.log(pendingMessages.val());
  });
```

But what the log is showing me is a weird JSON object, which I assume is part of Firebase's library or something.

```
node_1 | fb login/auth success
node_1 | { w: 
node_1 |    { m: { Ka: [Function: Sb], wa: [Object] },
node_1 |      aa: { m: [Object], aa: null, ub: [Object], zb: '' },
node_1 |      ub: { yd: [Object], cc: [Object] },
node_1 |      zb: null },
node_1 |   V: 
node_1 |    { k: 
node_1 |       { F: [Object],
node_1 |         Ua: [Object],
node_1 |         cd: null,
node_1 |         da: [Object],
```

and it goes on.

Could someone help direct me as to what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

[Edit] Also, my Firebase data has a very simple structure right now. It's simply like this:

```
[root]
    pending
        1:'Hello world'
    sent
        2:'Hello earth'
```

Comment: Weird. That output looks like what you'd normally get when you log a `DataSnapshot` (`pendingMessages` in your case). But you're clearly calling `val()` on it, which should return the JSON data only. If you're sure you're not logging a raw `DataSnapshot`, do you have some more info that could help me reproduce this behavior?

Comment: For example: this JavaScript snippet `new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/32544190/pending/').once('value', function(s) { console.log(s.val()); }, function(e) { console.error(e); })` prints `[1: "Hello world"]`, which is what I'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for the info. After your suggestion, I looked at it closer, and it appears that there was some sort of server-side caching going on that wasn't updating my code to include the .val() in the console.log.  It appears to be working now that I've flushed it and made sure the latest code was actually on the server.

Comment: Phew... glad that is sorted. I'll mark it as a "not reproducable".